# Py Search files in Folder and Subfolders

Tags: python, file, search, directory

I'm trying to find a list of files in a directory tree. In essence I provide a text file with all the terms I want to search for (~500) and have it look for them in a directory and subdirectories. However, I'm having problems with - I believe - the steps that the code takes and ends prematurely without searching in all folders.

The code I'm using is (`pattern` is the name of a text file):

```
import os

def locateA(pattern, root):
    file  = open(pattern, 'r')
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for word in files:
            for line in file:
                if line.strip() in word:
                    print os.path.join(path, word), line.strip()
```

Any ideas on where I'm mistaken?

Comment: I suggest to use the construct `with open(pattern, 'rU') as f:` and don't call your file `file` because `file` is a class in the builtin module.

Comment: Changed the name of file to something else. I'll investigate the construt you mentioned.

Comment: So what exactly are the symptoms of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All or part of the problem may be that you can only iterate through a file once unless you use [`file.seek()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to reset the current position in the file.

Make sure you seek back to the beginning of the file before attempting to loop through it again:

```
import os

def locateA(pattern, root):
    file  = open(pattern, 'r')
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for word in files:
            file.seek(0)             # this line is new
            for line in file:
                if line.strip() in word:
                    print os.path.join(path, word), line.strip()
```

Comment: Ah ha!, seems like this is working. Didn't know that you can only iterate once

Answer (score 0):

`for line in file` consumes the lines in `file` the first time and then is empty every time after that.

Try this instead, which fixes that and some other problems:

```
import os

def locateA(pattern, root):
    patterns = open(pattern, 'r').readlines() # patterns is now an array, no need to reread every time.
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for filename in files:
            for pattern in patterns:
                if pattern.strip() in filename:
                    print os.path.join(path, filename), pattern.strip()
```

Comment: Quick question, why do i need `filecontent = open(file,'r').read()` in the code? Does this open everyfile in the directory?

Comment: Sorry about that, I misread your question and thought you wanted to execute the equivalent of `grep` in each file. I now see you're actually matching the filenames. I corrected the example.